# Comparing ordering of sample and conditional distribution based on that sample

Tags: probability, order-statistics

I don't have a specific question, but just a request for resources and/or guidance.

Suppose we take $n$ draws from a distribution $F$. Suppose a particular sample is given by $\vec{\theta} = (\theta_1, \theta_2. \dots, \theta_n)$ where $\theta_1 > \theta_2 > \dots > \theta_n.$ Then suppose that, for each datum in the sample, we draw from a conditional distribution $G_i(t_i\mid \theta_i )$. For example, perhaps $F$ is normal, and then each $t_i \sim Uniform [\theta_i - c_i, \theta_i + c_i]$ for some constants $\vec{c}.$

What I am interested in is comparing the order of $t_1,\dots, t_n$ with the $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n$.

For example, if $c_i=0$ and thus $t_i = \theta_i$ for all $i$  then clearly the $\theta$'s and the $t$'s have the same order. But naturally I want to get some answer without making such a degenerate assumption on $G_i$. In general though, I would like to know if there is some field of probability or statistics that concerns itself with such relations between the ordering of data and the ordering of some other, related, sample.

Answer (score 1):

The field you are looking for is the study of [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic), though your particular problem is a complicated one.  I would recommend you start with the simpler problem of treating $\theta_1 > ... > \theta_n$ as fixed values, and concentrating entirely on the randomness in $G$.  This would already give you a mathematically complicated problem, but once you have solved this, the additional complexity of adding a random distribution $F$ then becomes a relatively simple marginalisation over your conditional results.